# Batch File Rename and Directory Autocount

Tags: batch-file

I need a way to make a directories containing the filename, but counting +1 for every one created.

How can i add +1 in front of the directory name created

Eg:

if Directory 1_xxx is present make 2_xxxxx

Currently i am using below to create a directory from Filename

File name Eg: Card_24ALL Sms.csv

Directory Output Eg: Card_24ALL Sms

Currently i have directories adding +1 manually 1_

1_Card_24ALL Sms ( With File Card_24ALL Sms.csv copied inside)

2_Card_25ALL Sms ( With File Card_25ALL Sms.csv copied inside)

3_Tjek_24ALL Sms ( With File Tjek_24ALL Sms.csv copied inside)

Using the below Code i can get directory added containing the given filename:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
```

But I have to manually create the number in front to get number_directory as the number in front can be 99_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@echo off
cd /d c:\temp
if exist cnt.txt for /f %%a in (cnt.txt) do set %%a
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
set /a cnt+=1
echo md "!cnt!_%%~na" 2>nul
echo move "%%a" "!cnt!_%%~na" >nul && (
Echo File %%~nxa moved to !cnt!_%%~na) || (Echo Move failed.)
)
>cnt.txt echo cnt=!cnt!
```

Remove the echo's from md and move once you verify the output.

Comment: Hi @Matt

Ok I got Directories :) Appreciate the Quick Response.

see now i have more files i have to add and running above then recreates folders 1_naming

lets say I ran four files, and need the directory naming to continue to 5_

Eg:

I ran four files using your code.
So i got
1_Naming
2_Naming
3_Naming
4_Naming

Perfect... i receive more file hourly how can i get 5_naming continuing from last number made, instead of 1_naming again.

Your help on this is Appreciated.

Comment: That's easy enough. I just had it write the last count to a file and read it when the script runs.

Comment: Thanks a Million I will try that just now. Thanks You.

Comment: PERFECT :)THANKS @Matt Williamson

Comment: Afternoon @Matt Williamson. 

I recently ran into the issue that the Stopped running unless i Move Line 5 and 6 together ...
cd /d c:\temp if exist cnt.txt for /f %%a in (cnt.txt) do set %%a

But with the above the Autocount Stopped Working and keeps resetting to 1.

I don't know if this might have been due to a Windows 7 Update.
Currently i am on Service Pack1

On my home pc this runs absolutely Fine.

I have been trying to resolve this with free time i have but with no Luck. 

Would Appreciate any Advice.